# how to view only file name by $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and not GET values appended with it

Tags: php

In one of my page `image.php?id=somenumber` , I am using `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` to recognize this page in the common sidebar. But using this `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` yields also the value of id as `image.php?id=32` which I don't want.

How do I only get the filename?

Comment: See http://php.net/parse_url.

Comment: strangely enough, now my server returns the same value for $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']. weirdo!

Comment: That often depends on server configuration because it's related to environment variables. Do some checkings if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, if you are using Apache at least, should cover what you need.  It should be the executed script without the query string and relative to the document root (as opposed to `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, `REQUEST_URI`, or `PHP_SELF`.

Comment: thank you.. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] gives the foldername/filename.php only.

Answer (score 4):

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
$file = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

Comment: $fileName=explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
echo end($fileName);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this to cut off the query string:

```
$_SERVER['SELF']=array_shift(explode('?',$_SERVER['SELF']));
```

Comment: It does for him, Jeff. He said that when he prints it out, he gets that environment variable. Servers are different. When your $_SERVER array does not have 'self', another server might return it. For example, there are a lot of differences between Apache and Nginx populated environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo parse_url('http://dummy.com/'.$_SERVER['SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

The `http://dummy.com/` part is only there because parse_url can't work with relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using? Mine (5.3.3) doesn't have $_SERVER['SELF'].

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] though gives the script name (image.php).

Comment: was that an answer or a question...?

Comment: remember that any `_SERVER` values are dependent on the server environment and have nothing to do with PHP whatsoever at all (okay .. a *little* to do)

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileName=explode("/",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
echo end($fileName);
```